# Koltin Flow is repeating execution using flatMapMerge

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I was trying to implement an approach to fetch products from two Data sources (Room & FirebaseFirestore) using Flows.
It was working fine until I noticed that the debugger was returning to the same break point infinitely. When the execution of "ViewmMdel.insertProducts(products)" ends, the debugger returns to Repository.getProducts(//) & repeats.

I changed the approach using only suspending functions & coroutines & works fine but I am curious about how I must to use Flows to implement this approach.

Maybe is only that flatMapMerge is in preview version.

Thanks in advance :D

This one is the implementation:

ViewModel:

```
    fun getProductNames(companyName: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.getProducts(companyName).catch {
                _event.value = AddSaleEvents.ShouldShowLoading(false)
                _event.value = AddSaleEvents.ProductsFailureResponse(it.message.toString())
            }.collect { products ->
                productsList = products
                if (products != emptyList<Product>()) {
                    _event.value = AddSaleEvents.ShouldShowLoading(false)
                    _event.value = AddSaleEvents.ProductsSuccessfulResponse(products)
                    insertProducts(products)
                } else {
                    _event.value = AddSaleEvents.ShouldShowLoading(false)
                    _event.value = AddSaleEvents.ProductsSuccessfulResponse(products)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Repository:

```
    @OptIn(FlowPreview::class)
    override suspend fun getProducts(compnayName: String): Flow<List<Product>> {
        return localDataSource.getProducts().flatMapMerge { list -> // LINE RUNNING INFINITELY
            getProductsFromFirebase(list, compnayName)
        }.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO).catch {
            Log.d("Error", it.message.toString())
        }
    }

    private fun getProductsFromFirebase(products: List<Product>, compnayName: String) = flow {
        if (products.isEmpty()) {
            remoteDataSource.getProducts(compnayName).collect {
                emit(it)
            }
        } else {
            emit(products)
        }
    }
```

LocalDataSource with Room:

```
override suspend fun getProducts(): Flow<List<Product>> = saleDao.getProducts()
```

Firebase Data Source:

```
    override suspend fun getProducts(company: String): Flow<List<Product>> = flow {
        val response = fireStore.collection("products").whereEqualTo("company", company).get()
        response.await()
        if (response.isSuccessful && !response.result.isEmpty) {
            emit(response.result.toObjects(FirebaseProduct::class.java).toEntity())
        }
    }.catch {
        Log.d("Error", it.message.toString())
    }
```

How can I chain the response of a flow to trigger another one inside the MVVM Architecture + Clean Architecture?
6 if it is possible, I want to understand the reason the code is repeating infinitely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `insertProducts(products)` triggers room's DAO.

So `localDataSource.getProducts()` is a [observable read query](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/async-queries#observable)
Observable queries are read operations that emit new values whenever there are changes to any of the tables that are referenced by the query.

Try to change LocalDataSource

```
interface SaleDao { 
 
    // fun getProducts(): Flow<List<Product>>
    suspend fun getProducts(): List<Product>
}
```

Comment: That explains my current problem, thanks for the comment. 
I will change the implementation.